# C# listbox selected index stays at -1 when run

Tags: c#, listbox, arduino-ide, serial-communication

I am trying to do a serial com to Arduino but when I try to send the data, my speed listbox selected index stays at -1 when I run it. But the front part runs okay. How do I remove the '-' sign and make the number increase? So I'm able to get 1, 2 and 3.

This is my code:

```
else if (Action2CB.Text == "Action2")
{
    // send action A only
    DataOut = Action1CB.SelectedIndex.ToString() + '_' + A1RepetitionNUD.Value.ToString() + '_' + A1SpeedLB.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    serialPort1.WriteLine(DataOut);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: No Value is selected that's why it's returning -1 [ListBox.SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: Can you explain more what are you trying to do?

Comment: your listbox doesn't have any value selected... I guess you're reading the value before the selection takes place (in constructor before InitializeComponent is called?)

Comment: When I select the item from my listbox, it will be already be connected to the serial port. So when i select the item, '-1' will appear on my serial port. But i dont want it to only be -1

Comment: I want the number to increase but at the same time, i want to remove the negative sign. But everytime when i try to run the program to my serial comm, everything else infront works fine. Just the listbox part it keeps show -1 no matter what i select from my listbox

Comment: are you reading the value of the listbox again on [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Yeah I am reading the value from the listbox

Comment: Please define your question more, for all we can see now is that you're getting the selected index of a checkbox and it's returning -1, this is not really enough to help you